# Add rows with date and fill empty cells with previous row value

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a following table in Vertica:

```
Item_id  event_date  Price
   A     2019-01-01  100
   A     2019-01-04  200
   B     2019-01-05  150
   B     2019-01-06  250
   B     2019-01-09  350
```

As you see, there are some missing dates between 2019-01-04 and 2019-01-01, and also 2019-01-09 - 2019-01-06.
What I need is to add for each item_id missing dates between the existing ones, and as the price cell will be NULL, fill it with the previous date Price.
So it will be like this:

```
Item_id  event_date  Price
   A     2019-01-01  100
   A     2019-01-02  100
   A     2019-01-03  100
   A     2019-01-04  200
   B     2019-01-05  150
   B     2019-01-06  250
   B     2019-01-07  250
   B     2019-01-08  250
   B     2019-01-09  350
```

I tried to go with

```
SELECT Item_id, event_date
       CASE Price WHEN 0 THEN NVL( LAG( CASE Price WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE Price END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ), 0 ) ELSE Price END AS Price_new
FROM   item_price_table
```

from this article https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/17/how-to-fill-sparse-data-with-the-previous-non-empty-value-in-sql/ , but it seems it works for SQL Server, but not for Vertica, as there are no IGNORE NULLS function...
Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume you have a calendar table.  In Vertica, you can then use `last_value(ignore nulls)` to fill in the rest:

```
select c.event_date, i.item_id,
       coalesce(ipt.price,
                last_value(ipt.price ignore nulls) over (partition by i.item_id order by c.event_date)
               ) as price
from calendar c cross join
     (select distinct item_id from item_price_table) i left join
     item_price_table ipt
     on i.item_it = ipt.item_id and c.date = ipt.event_date
```

Comment: cool, it seems as a good one! could you please explain if there is any other way to escape the cross join? the query is being too big and heavy at the end because of it...

Comment: @Polly . . . In the end, you want one row per event date and item.  That means that you are going to be generating  the same rows as the `cross join`, even if you found another method.   So, I don't think there is going to be a way around that because of the volume of data being returned.

Answer (score 1):

I was waiting for that one....!

I just love Vertica's TIMESERIES clause !
It works on TIMESTAMPs, not DATEs, so I have to cast back and forth, but it's unbeatable.

See here:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                        
input(item_id,event_dt,price) AS (
          SELECT 'A',DATE '2019-01-01',100
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',DATE '2019-01-04',200
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',DATE '2019-01-05',150
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',DATE '2019-01-06',250
UNION ALL SELECT 'B',DATE '2019-01-09',350
)
SELECT
  item_id
, event_dts::DATE AS event_dt
, TS_FIRST_VALUE(price) AS price
FROM input
TIMESERIES event_dts AS '1 DAY' OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY event_dt::timestamp)
-- out  item_id |  event_dt  | price 
-- out ---------+------------+-------
-- out  A       | 2019-01-01 |   100
-- out  A       | 2019-01-02 |   100
-- out  A       | 2019-01-03 |   100
-- out  A       | 2019-01-04 |   200
-- out  B       | 2019-01-05 |   150
-- out  B       | 2019-01-06 |   250
-- out  B       | 2019-01-07 |   250
-- out  B       | 2019-01-08 |   250
-- out  B       | 2019-01-09 |   350
-- out (9 rows)
-- out 
-- out Time: First fetch (9 rows): 68.057 ms. All rows formatted: 68.221 ms
;
```

Need explanations?

Happy playing ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code on the top of my head, but to add the missing dates you'll want to create a Calendar table and join to that. Then you can use the lag function to replace the null Price with the one above it. There's plenty of code if you search CTE to create calendar table.